# Dropzone always return 'empty($_FILES)' as true

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I need to add drag and drop to my web page. I'm trying to get dropped image and upload them to my database.
**HTML**

```
<form action="parser.php" id="file-up" class="dropzone">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="file-up_btn"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#file-up_btn').click(function(e){
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myId", {
    autoQueue: false,
    url: "/parser.php",                        
});
    console.log("Uploading");
});
```

Dropzone shows that the uploading finished successfully. But it does not show any files in the php file.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES)){
    echo 'Inside';
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $dir_seperator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $folder = "uploads";

//$destination_path = dirname(__FILE_).$dir_seperator.$folder.$dir_seperator;
$destination_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Tux');
echo '<h1>Uploading section $destination_path</h1>';
$target_path = $destination_path.$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($temp,$target_path);
echo 'Updated';
}else{
    echo '<h1>No files</h1>';
}

?>
```

it always returns No files. I am new to DropZone. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried by adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form?

Comment: I haven't. I'll try that.

Comment: Tried that. It does not work

Comment: Is the file data passing through in your request?

Comment: try. if(isset($_FILES['file']))

Comment: It doesn't work. :(

Comment: "#myId" or #file-up?

Answer (score 0):

Two thinks to check:

- id isn't the same. 
  in js: "#myId"
  in html: #file-up or #file-up_btn
  There no myid in html to refer so img isn't added to form.
- from logical behaviour:
  empty($_FILES) is true when no files are transmited
  !empty($_FILES) is false because of !. So no file is attach. 
  Check Developer Tools->Network and check Preserve log. Check what header is sent with what data (maybe nothing is sent etc, it is half success when you can inform if file is added to form data).

Screenshoot to show what we all need to help: [developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rynuu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old topic. But I had the same problem and solved it. You should check the initial settings for dropzone. There is a bunch of parameters. Make sure the one - **paramName: "file",** is matching with the php **$_FILES['file']** array. Also the parameter **url: "upload.php",** should point to the PHP file with uploading procedure:

example upload.php file

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){ 
 
    // File path configuration 
    $uploadDir = "./upload/"; 
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $uploadFilePath = $uploadDir.$fileName; 
     
    // Upload file to server 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFilePath))
    { 
    echo "files uploaded susccesfully";
    } 
    else
    
    {
    echo "something wrong";
    }
    
    }
```

example my_dropzone.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sortable').sortable();
   
});

//DropzoneJS snippet - js
$.getScript('./js/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.js',function(){
  // instantiate the uploader
  $('#file-dropzone').dropzone({ 
    url: "./upload.php",
    maxFilesize: 100,
    paramName: "file",
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 99999,
    previewsContainer: '.visual', 
    previewTemplate : $('.preview').html(),
    init: function() {
      this.on('completemultiple', function(file, json) {
       $('.sortable').sortable('enable');
      });
      this.on('success', function(file, json) {
        alert('abc');
      });
      
      this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
       
      });
      
      this.on('drop', function(file) {
        console.log('File',file)
      }); 
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

example index.html file

```
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropzone/4.0.1/min/dropzone.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/my_dropzone.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="/action.php" class="dropzone" drop-zone="" id="file-dropzone" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   </form>
        <ul class="visual sortable dropzone-previews" style="border:1px solid #000">
          
        </ul>
    <div class="preview" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <div>
        <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
          <img data-dz-thumbnail />
        <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
        <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
        <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
        <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </li>  
    </div>
    
    <script src="./js/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/my_dropzone.js"></script>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Example (without php code) taken from https://codepen.io/malkafly/pen/gbVYZb